# Posting dynamic live location GPS Coordinates to the Server from android studio

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

What i am trying to do is track a location of the vehicle, where i am getting the vehicle location being traced up at regular intervals/at specified distance. The next thing was to post the location details to the server, i do am acheiving it with the Volley library but its being posted only once to the server but not a regular intervals of time.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startBackgroundService() {
        if(!registered) {
            IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter(JOB_STATE_CHANGED);
            i.addAction(LOCATION_ACQUIRED);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(jobStateChanged, i);
        }
        JobScheduler jobScheduler =
                (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        assert jobScheduler != null;
        jobScheduler.schedule(new JobInfo.Builder(LocationJobService.LOCATION_SERVICE_JOB_ID,
                new ComponentName(this, LocationJobService.class))
                .setOverrideDeadline(500)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
                .build());
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(15000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Location request created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                // location requests here.
                // ...
                bService.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        });
        task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                switch (statusCode) {
                    case CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                        // by showing the user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                        // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Starting Location Updates", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
                    // Update UI with location data
                    // ...
                    updateMarker(location);
                }
            }

            ;
        };
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"location permission required !!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);
        button.setTag("f");
        button.setText("STOP FOREGROUND TRACKING");
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location update started",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (button.getTag().equals("s")) {
            Log.d("TRACK", "stopLocationUpdates: updates never requested, no-op.");
            return;
        }

        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        button.setTag("s");
        button.setText("START FOREGROUND TRACKING");
        bService.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Location update stopped.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        try {
            if (registered) {
                unregisterReceiver(jobStateChanged);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if( requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Log.i("Dash", "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                    createLocationRequest();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
//                    showTimeoutDialog("Without location access, GreenPool Enterprise can't be used !!", true);
                    Log.i("Dash", "User choose not to make required location settings changes.");
                    break;
            }
        }else{
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    static void animateMarkerToICS(Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition) {
        TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
            @Override
            public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                return interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
            }
        };
        Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
        animator.setDuration(3000);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
                handler.post(moveThread);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

            }
        });
        animator.start();
    }

    public static LatLng interpolate(float fraction, LatLng a, LatLng b) {
        // function to calculate the in between values of old latlng and new latlng.
        // To get more accurate tracking(Car will always be in the road even when the latlng falls away from road), use roads api from Google apis.
        // As it has quota limits I didn't have used that method.
        double lat = (b.latitude - a.latitude) * fraction + a.latitude;
        double lngDelta = b.longitude - a.longitude;

        // Take the shortest path across the 180th meridian.
        if (Math.abs(lngDelta) > 180) {
            lngDelta -= Math.signum(lngDelta) * 360;
        }
        double lng = lngDelta * fraction + a.longitude;
        return new LatLng(lat, lng);
    }

    private class MoveThread implements Runnable {
        LatLng newPoint;
        float zoom = 16;

        void setNewPoint(LatLng latLng, float zoom){
            this.newPoint = latLng;
            this.zoom = zoom;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final CameraUpdate point = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(newPoint,zoom);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMap.animateCamera(point);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void updateMarker(final Location location) {
        if(location == null){
            return;
        }
        if(mMap!=null && mapLoaded){
            if(carMarker==null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Updating Marker Locations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                oldLocation = location;
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                BitmapDescriptor car = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_car);
                markerOptions.icon(car);
                markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f); // set the car image to center of the point instead of anchoring to above or below the location
                markerOptions.flat(true); // set as true, so that when user rotates the map car icon will remain in the same direction
                markerOptions.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
                carMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                if(location.hasBearing()){ // if location has bearing set the same bearing to marker(if location is acquired using GPS bearing will be available)
                    bearing = location.getBearing();
                }else{
                    bearing = 0; // no need to calculate bearing as it will be the first point
                }
                carMarker.setRotation(bearing);
                moveThread  = new MoveThread();
                moveThread.setNewPoint(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),16);
                handler.post(moveThread);
                try {
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                    String URL = "abc.com/location";
                    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
                    jsonBody.put("latitude", location.getLatitude());
                    jsonBody.put("longitude", location.getLongitude());
                    final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Locations are posted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("VOLLEY", response);
                            parseData(response);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
                        }
                    }) {
                        @Override
                        public String getBodyContentType() {
                            return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                        }

                        @Override
                        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                            try {
                                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                                return null;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                            String responseString = "";
                            if (response != null) {
                                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);
                                // can get more details such as response.headers
                            }
                            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                        }
                    };

                    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }else{
                if(location.hasBearing()){// if location has bearing set the same bearing to marker(if location is acquired using GPS bearing will be available)
                    bearing = location.getBearing();
                }else { // if not, calculate bearing between old location and new location point
                    bearing = oldLocation.bearingTo(location);
                }
                carMarker.setRotation(bearing);
                moveThread.setNewPoint(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()),mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom); // set the map zoom to current map's zoom level as user may zoom the map while tracking.
                animateMarkerToICS(carMarker,new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())); // animate the marker smoothly
            }
        }else{
            Log.e("map null or not loaded","");
        }
    }

    private void parseData(String response){
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            if (object.getString("status").equals("true")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Location Details Posted to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You wanna let Android Studio post to your server?

Comment: Yes i did post the data from android studio to server at intervals using runnable and handler, but only when i open the app latlng details of that particular location was going not periodically

Comment: I specially asked thinking that your Android app running on an Android device would do that while you are not at home. And Android Studio mostly stays at home...